# Can a dedicated circuit have a junction box somewhere between the fixture and the panel?

Tags: electrical

Whoever installed the central air conditioning unit in my house correctly used a dedicated circuit, however, they cut the wire too short (there is a ~12 inch splice in the panel) and the wire was improperly run through an air return vent. I disconnected the wire from the fixture and pulled it into the house and I would like to eliminate the splice inside the panel which would mean that I would need to have a junction box in the basement and approximately 3-4 feet of additional wire from the junction box to the fixture.

Would this still be considered a dedicated circuit and is it an appropriate amend to the issue?

Comment: A dedicated circuit means it is hard-wired to a single appliance (e.g. dishwasher) or has a single outlet (most motors that "plug in" such as a fridge). I have a junction box in the basement with two circuits passing through it, one of which is for the washing machine. That is still a dedicated motor circuit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as nothing else is connected to the circuit, even if it traverses a j-box along the way, it is still dedicated.

Kudos, for remediating the duct run.  The splice in the panel isn't best practice, but if terminated properly, is O.K..